# how do I disable a bogus pylint warning for a multi-line string only

Tags: python, pylint

How do I disable a bogus pylint warning for a multiline string just for that string?

The first disable works,  the second (bogus warning) does not.

Edited after initial answer for a simpler example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 0!= 1 # pylint: disable=C0322
print {''
# pylint: disable=C0322
: '''%      
'''
# pylint: enable=C0322
}
```

I get

```
************* Module foobar
C0322:  4: Operator not preceded by a space
print {''

: '''%
     ^
```

Answer (score 10):

you can do something like

```
# pylint: disable=C0322
print 0!= 1
print '''%
'''
# pylint: enable=C0322
```

Comment: yes, in this example this works, but in my extended example does not.  I will edit the question to give a bigger example, where your answer does not work.

Comment: can you tell me which pylint version are you using?